# How to get Google Plus Notifications count?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, google-chrome-extension, google-plus

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension and I want to retrieve Google+ notifications count for current user, in a script running in the background.
Is it possible? I studied the Google+ APIs at https://developers.google.com/+/api/ but it seems not supported yet.

How is it possible to retrieve the count value anyway? I tried with a (cross-domain permitted) AJAX request, but the notification value seems generated at runtime, in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that there's no way to access the notifications or the current notification count from the official API. Since scraping pages is [against the developer policy](https://developers.google.com/+/policies#what-you-can-not-do), and results in really brittle integrations, I'd recommend against trying to reverse engineer it.

A [request for this API](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=96) is being tracked in the platform issue tracker. If you star the  issue you'll be notified when it's updated.

Answer (score 2):

there is no way to get notifications from google + api.