# Which API to use to gain access to the notification of google?

Tags: android

I'm building an application to gather unread notifications from social medias

I realize that Google+ uses a universal notification icon to remind the user

[image]

I searched around the web to find exactly what is the API called in google but mostly it returns the result of how to get access to the notification bar of the phone.

Could anyone shed some light on this ?

Edit :

Sorry didn't mentioned that the application is an android application.

Comment: how come this is tagged "android"?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Sorry didn't mentioned that the application i'm building is an android application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API for Google+ does not support getting notification numbers or the individual notifications (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10506707/5117760)). If you are asking for a way to do something similar with other services, look at their respective API.

Comment: Looks like i'm toasted , guess the only work around is to listen to notification bars from the phone

Comment: If my answer answered your question would you please accept it?